# Implementing mulit-selection list in Libre office calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to implement a multiple selection list in libre office. I am inexperienced with excel. Any suggestion or solutions will be appriciated.

Comment: Welcome! See [**here**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/create-a-multiple-selection-dropdown-list-for-librecalc/65131/7?u=johnsun) - https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/create-a-multiple-selection-dropdown-list-for-librecalc/65131?u=johnsun

Comment: Decide if you are using Excel or Libreoffice. They may well behave differently.

Comment: @SolarMike I am using Libre Office.